# Name conflict between libraries

Tags: c++, windows, namespaces, conflict, allegro

I'd like to include two libraries: `<allegro.h>` and `<windows.h>` in my project, but I can't compile it. The IDE shows such errors:

```
error C2371: 'BITMAP' : redefinition; different basic types
error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded
error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'WinMain' not allowed
```

I understand both of the libraries have for example a structure called BITMAP so they're in a conflict. What should I do to compile my project with these libraries? I thought about namespaces but I couldn't use it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special fix for that provided by allegro. Include "winalleg.h" (instead of "Windows.h") right after "allegro.h".

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search suggested using `#include <winalleg.h>` instead of `#include <windows.h>`.